# Fastest way to determine the non-zero minimum

Tags: c++, algorithm, minimum

Having an array of for instance 4 integers how can one determine it's non-zero minimum - in the fastest way ?

Comment: This will depend heavily on the specific platform you're working on.

Comment: I heavily doubt minimum finding is a bottleneck in your code.

Comment: You can't do better than the obvious way: iterate over all 4, keeping track of the smallest yet seen.

Comment: @Beta: Indeed, but there may be varying ways to express that in code, some of which exploit the particular CPU architecture better than others.

Comment: What if the array contains two of the same numbers, which are minimum?

Comment: Assuming the array is in random order, there is no way to make this operation anything less than O(n) because you must inspect every element in order to determine which element of the entire set is the minimum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a parallel solution to this problem, but its probably not worth the effort.

First we define an operation `xchg(m, n)` over an array *a*:

```
xchg(m, n) => ((a[m] > a[n] && a[n] != 0) || a[m] == 0) ? swap(a[m],a[n])
```

This operation sorts two elements 'm' and 'n' in ascending order if they both contain non-zero values, or swaps them if the value in the 'm' element is zero.

Next we execute a set of five such operations as follows:

```
xchg(0,2) xchg(1,3)
xchg(0,1) xchg(2,3)
xchg(1,2)
```

The paired `xchg` operations can be executed in parallel, reducing the time cost by 40% over a strictly sequential execution. When we're finished, any non-zero elements in the array will be sorted in ascending order. The smallest-value element will be in a[0]. If that value is zero, there are no non-zero values in the array.

This solution takes advantage of the inherent parallelism provided by sorting networks ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), but a sequential scan of 4 elements also uses no more than three comparison operations, and crucially requires half as many storage writes on average:

**sequential scan**

```
int v = a[0]
for (n = 1; n < 4; n++) {
   if ((a[n] < v && a[n] != 0 ) || v == 0) v = a[n]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Unless you keep the minimum value as elements are added to the array, or you keep the array in a sorted order - I see no other solution but to iterate every member to determine the minimum value.

There is no 'fast' way of testing each member.

Generally I suggest do not optimize something unless it actually proves to be slow. The old rule of your program spends 90% of its time in 10% of the code generally holds true. So does the rules that programmers are 99.99% likely to optimize code not in that 10%.

Profile your code - profile your code - profile your code

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the input. If the array is not sorted, then you'll have to loop through the full array. If the array is sorted, then you just need to loop until you find something that isn't zero - it's much shorter.

Answer (score 3):

If we're thinking of micro-optimizations, then potentially it could be faster to compute `min(min(a,b),min(c,d))` instead of `min(min(min(a,b),c),d)` on a modern out-of-order processor, because of less sequential dependencies: in the former the processor can compute `min(a,b)` and `min(c,d)` independently in parallel, if it has sufficient execution units available.  This is assuming that the processor has a conditional move instruction, so that computing `min` does not require branching.

Comment: This will not find a non zero minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Well the fastest way to code it is `std::min({a,b,c,d})`.

On a more serious note: If you application is bottlenecking on something like taking the minimum of a lot of values, a better solution might be to find a way to split  that minimum finding task into parts and send to the GPU(or many threads), which can then operate many minimum finding calculations at the same time.

Parallelism would probably help more than trying to write a minimum function in assembly.

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the question as it may yield zero. I think this version of `std::min()` also takes a comparison object i.e. it should be possible to map the zeros to infinity.

Comment: As far as I know there is only `std::min(a,b)`